# Move_base launching error

Tags: navigation, move-base, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
We made our own move_base package according to the original one and tried to launch it on the PR2. But ros could not find our package. We already set up our ROS PACKAGE PATH to our workspace.
The error are following

```
[c2-0]: ERROR: cannot launch node of type [move_base_3/move_base]: move_base_3
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
[c2-0]: ... done launching nodes
```

And here is our ros package path messages

```
/u/jfasola/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:/u/jfasola/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70861/move_base-launching-error/) by [HanXiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/5433/hanxiao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2013-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on 2013-08-02**:
can you post your launch file as well?

**Comment by [HanXiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/5433/hanxiao/) on 2013-08-05**:
I solved that problem. I targeted the node to c2, but it was copied to c1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The launch is failing on c2 because your environment loader is not setting your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH up properly on c2.

Please see: http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/Tutorials/Setting%20up%20the%20ROS_ENV_LOADER

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HanXiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/5433/hanxiao/) on 2013-08-05**:
Yes, we set the route to c1 because our code were on c1.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-08-05**:
c1 and c2 have the same filesystem; anything you do on one machine is also on the other. Your ROS environment variables are not automatically transferred from one to the other when you do a roslaunch; this is why you must set up an environment-loader.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-08-05**:
I *STRONGLY* recommend running move_base on c2, because the laser drivers are on c2, and it will significantly decrease the amount of traffic and latency between servers if move_base and the laser drivers run on the same machine.

**Comment by [HanXiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/5433/hanxiao/) on 2013-08-06**:
Thanks! We will try to do that. By the way, how to specify c1 and c2 when copying codes in pr2?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-08-06**:
You can specify which machine a node runs on by using the machine="" property of the  tag in your launch file. You do not need to copy anything from c1 to c2.